# Losing data when scraping with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

UPDATE(4/10/2018):
So I found that my problem was that the information wasn't available in the source code which means I have to use Selenium.

UPDATE:
I played around with this problem a bit more.  What I did was instead or running soup, I just took `pageH`, decoded it into a string and made a text file out of it, and I found that the '{{ optionTitle }}' or '{{priceFormat (showPrice, session.currency)}}' were from the template section separately stated in the HTML file.  Which I THINK means that I was just looking at the wrong place.  I am still unsure but that's what I think.

So now I have a new question.  After having looked at the text file, I am now realizing that the information necessary is not even in `pageH`.  At the place where it should give me the information I am looking for, it says instead:

`<bread-crumbs :location="location" :product-name="product.productName"></bread-crumbs>`
`<product-info ref="productInfo" :basic="product" :location="location" :prod-info="prodInfo"></product-info>`

What does this mean?/Is there a way to get through this to get to the information?

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am trying to collect the names/prices for products off of a website.  I am unsure if the data is being lost because of the html parser or because of BeautifulSoup but what is happening is that once I do get to the position I want to be in, what is returned instead of the specific name/price is '{{ optionTitle }}' or '{{priceFormat (showPrice, session.currency)}}'.  After I get the url using `pageH = urllib.request.urlopen()`, the code that gives this result is:

```
pageS = soup(pageH, "html.parser")
pageB = pageS.body
names = pageB.findAll("h4")
optionTitle = names[3].get_text()
optionPrice = names[5].get_text()
```

Because this didn't work, I tried going about it a different way and looked for more specific tags, but the section of the code that mattered just does not show.  It completely disappears.  Is there something I can do to get the specific names/prices or is this a security measure that I cannot work through?

Comment: These double curly brace things look suspiciously like Angular templates, which probably means you need a JavaScript engine/browser to render the page.

Answer (score 2):

The {{}} syntax looks like Angular. Try [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) to do the rendering (by using render())and get the content afterward. Example shows below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')
r.html.render()
r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']

'<time>25</time>'
```

Comment: Could you clarify what type of object session is supposed to be in this case?

Comment: "session" is a HTMLSession object from requests_html library. Just edit the reply above for your reference. Cheers:)